# Azure WebJob does not get response from PostAsync call

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have taken a Windows Service, modified it to be a Console app, then Published it as a WebJob.  When it does a PostAsync command it gets no response AND does not execute the Console.WriteLine immediately following the PostAsync command.

Here's the code:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Querying for access credentials...");
            HttpResponseMessage responsePut = null;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PostAsync call");
                responsePut = await client.PostAsync("/oauth/access_token", new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
                Console.WriteLine("Returned from PostAsync call");
            }
            catch (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to the server (HttpRequestException)..." + err.InnerException);
                throw new Exception("Unable to connect to the server (HttpRequestException)..." + err.InnerException);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to the server (Exception)..." + err.Message + "::" + err.InnerException);
                throw new Exception("Unable to connect to the server (Exception)..." + err.InnerException);
            }
```

The Azure Console Log is as follows:

```
[05/01/2018 05:45:31 > e559bd: INFO] Querying for access credentials...
[05/01/2018 05:45:31 > e559bd: INFO] PostAsync call
[05/01/2018 05:45:32 > e559bd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
[05/01/2018 05:45:32 > e559bd: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
```

This code works as a Windows Service and as a Windows Console App, but fails on Azure.

What can I do to determine what Azure is doing to me and/or suggestions to do this differently.

Comment: Try running the same console app on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console.   See if it gives more clue.

Comment: You could remote [debug it with VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebugwj) to get more information.

Comment: See [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues) which expands on Suwat's suggestion. Basically, getting WebJobs out of the equation and getting it down to the smallest possible repro is the first step.

Answer (score 1):

I created a support ticket and got a reasonably quick response.

The line of code that includes the PostAsync had to be modified as follows:

```
responsePut = client.PostAsync("/oauth/access_token", new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")).Result;
```

Note the removal of the `await` and the addition of the `.Result`.

This was considered a 'syntax error', which I disagree with!  But it solved the problem.